# How to search word in between text lines and replace it in Text file with Python?

Tags: python

I have a file from CNC machine. I need to change in a text file two parameters `N1530 M136 --> N1530 M128` and `N1710 M137 --> N1710 M129`, for a specific CNC Machine name, in this case it's "803" in line N1240 (all these line numbers change in other files).
I was trying with Regex, to find block of text to look in, and to replace only the specific `M136 --> M128` in this block of text. But Regex gave me only the result of finding the Machine name "803".

I used `(?:\G(?!\A)|\"603\")(?:(?!\:ENDFOR).)*?\KM136` in regex101 website, and it worked. But when I selected Python then it doesn't work at all. I understand that there is a difference in the syntax or just Python can't handle it this way.

Also maybe there is a better solution in Python for this kind of problem.

FULL TEXT FILE

```
[COMMENTO]
VER 3.2.0 - Build 449
%

[PARAMETRI01]
N10 G71 LX=1270.83375 LY=575.39375 LZ=106.00000 P103=1122
%

[SEIFERT01]
;SETPEN
"ALL" ZP 1,2,3;
"STOPS + SUCTION CUPS" ZP 1,2;
"STOPS" ZP 1;
"SUCTION CUPS" ZP 2;
"PROFILE" ZP 3;
;ENDSEC
;BATTUTE
SP1;
PU;
PA -15.00000,203.70029;
PD;
CI 13.00000;
PU;
PA 225.90810,-15.00000;
PD;
CI 13.00000;
PU;
PA 665.50118,-15.00000;
PD;
CI 13.00000;
PU;
;ENDSEC
;VENTOSE
SP2;
PU;
PA 806.67132,89.33461;
PD;
CI 60.00000;
PU;
PA 806.67132,276.96581;
PD;
CI 60.00000;
PU;
PA 449.27857,171.53494;
PD;
CI 60.00000;
PU;
PA 111.54242,264.45706;
PD;
CI 60.00000;
PU;
PA 99.03368,91.12157;
PD;
CI 60.00000;
PU;
;ENDSEC
;PROFILI
SP3;
PU;
PA 2.00000,0.00000;
PD;
AA 2.00000,2.00000,-90.00;
PA 0.00000,363.00000;
AA 2.00000,363.00000,-90.00;
PA 900.00000,365.00000;
AA 900.00000,363.00000,-90.00;
PA 902.00000,2.00000;
AA 900.00000,2.00000,-90.00;
PA 2.00000,0.00000;
PU;
;ENDSEC
%

[UTENSILI01]
801
802
803
%

[LAVORAZIONI01]
 1 - 0 - Contouring - 801 - EDGE MILL H8
 1 - 1 - Contouring - 802 - EDGE GRINDER H8
 2 - Contouring - 803 - POLISH H8 TEST
%

[CONTORNATURA01]

N20 R1=-221.11250
N30 R2=1049.72125
N40 R4=-142.86250
N50 R3=432.53125
N60 R6=-13.00000
N70 R5=93.00000
N80 R7=P007
N90 P619=0.00000
N100 P620=0.00000
N110 P621=902.00000
N120 P622=365.00000
N130 P623=-1.00000
N140 P624=-1.00000
N150 P625=-1.00000
N160 P626=-1.00000
N170 P826=180
N180 P827=10
N190 ST1="801"
N200 L=PINIZIO
N210 L=PZHIGH

N220 JM(P010=4):1000

N230 JM(((P010=2)#(P010=3))~(R7=1)):1
N240 JM(((P010=2)#(P010=3))~(R7=2)):2
N250 JM(((P010=2)#(P010=3))~(R7=3)):3
N260 JM(P010<>1):99999

:1
N270 R7=1
N280 ST1="801"
N290 L=PCAMBIOUT
:FOR P500=P008 TO (P001-1)
N300 L=PZTRASLA
N310 P011=2.00000
N320 P012=-75.47500
N330 P013=80.00000
N340 P252=0.00000
N350 P514=0.000
N360 P501=0
N370 P607=0
N380 P046=0
N390 P077=2500
N400 P608=1
N410 L=PRELAV2
N420 L=PREFRINT01ON
N430 L=PREFREXT01ON
N440 PS01=-6000
N450 L=PSTARTROT01
N460 L=PTCPYES
N470 G01 G300 X=2.00000 Y=-75.47500
N480 P014=P069
N490 L=PONINT2
N500 G01 G300 Z=P014
N510 G68
N520 L=PBLOCCAC
N530 L=PRPMOK01
N540 M33200
N550 G01 G42 X=-73.07500 Y=-75.47500  F=1750 
N560 G02 X=2.00000 Y=-0.40000  I=2.00000 J=-75.47500 
N570 M136
N580 G01 X=900.00000 Y=-0.40000  F=2500 
N590 G03 X=902.40000 Y=2.00000  I=900.00000 J=2.00000 
N600 G01 X=902.40000 Y=363.00000  
N610 G03 X=900.00000 Y=365.40000  I=900.00000 J=363.00000 
N620 G01 X=2.00000 Y=365.40000  
N630 G03 X=-0.40000 Y=363.00000  I=2.00000 J=363.00000 
N640 G01 X=-0.40000 Y=2.00000  
N650 G03 X=2.00000 Y=-0.40000  I=2.00000 J=2.00000 
N660 M137
N670 G02 X=77.07500 Y=-75.47500  I=2.00000 J=-75.47500 
N680 M021
N690 G01 G40 X=2.00000 Y=-75.47500  
N700 G01 G300 X=2.00000 Y=-75.47500 Z=80.00000+P102 
N710 L=PTCPNO
N720 L=PSBLOCCAC
N730 L=POFFINT2

:ENDFOR
N740 JM(P010=2):99999

:2
N750 R7=2
N760 ST1="802"
N770 L=PCAMBIOUT
:FOR P500=P008 TO (P001-1)
N780 L=PZTRASLA
N790 P011=2.00000
N800 P012=-71.40000
N810 P013=80.00000
N820 P252=0.00000
N830 P514=0.000
N840 P501=0
N850 P607=0
N860 P046=0
N870 P077=2500
N880 P608=1
N890 L=PRELAV2
N900 L=PREFRINT01ON
N910 L=PREFREXT01ON
N920 PS01=-5500
N930 L=PSTARTROT01
N940 L=PTCPYES
N950 G01 G300 X=2.00000 Y=-71.40000
N960 P014=P069
N970 L=PONINT2
N980 G01 G300 Z=P014
N990 G68
N1000 L=PBLOCCAC
N1010 L=PRPMOK01
N1020 M33200
N1030 G01 G42 X=-69.40000 Y=-71.40000  F=1750 
N1040 G02 X=2.00000 Y=0.00000  I=2.00000 J=-71.40000 
N1050 M136
N1060 G01 X=900.00000 Y=0.00000  F=2500 
N1070 G03 X=902.00000 Y=2.00000  I=900.00000 J=2.00000 
N1080 G01 X=902.00000 Y=363.00000  
N1090 G03 X=900.00000 Y=365.00000  I=900.00000 J=363.00000 
N1100 G01 X=2.00000 Y=365.00000  
N1110 G03 X=0.00000 Y=363.00000  I=2.00000 J=363.00000 
N1120 G01 X=0.00000 Y=2.00000  
N1130 G03 X=2.00000 Y=0.00000  I=2.00000 J=2.00000 
N1140 M137
N1150 G02 X=73.40000 Y=-71.40000  I=2.00000 J=-71.40000 
N1160 M021
N1170 G01 G40 X=2.00000 Y=-71.40000  
N1180 G01 G300 X=2.00000 Y=-71.40000 Z=80.00000+P102 
N1190 L=PTCPNO
N1200 L=PSBLOCCAC
N1210 L=POFFINT2

:ENDFOR
N1220 JM(P010=2):99999

:3
N1230 R7=3
N1240 ST1="803"
N1250 L=PCAMBIOUT
:FOR P500=P008 TO (P001-1)
N1260 L=PZTRASLA
N1270 P011=2.00000
N1280 P012=-75.75000
N1290 P013=80.00000
N1300 P252=0.00000
N1310 P514=0.000
N1320 P501=0
N1330 P607=0
N1340 P046=0
N1350 P077=2200
N1360 P608=1
N1370 L=PRELAV2
N1380 L=PREFRINT01ON
N1390 L=PREFREXT01ON
N1400 PS01=-3600
N1410 L=PSTARTROT01
N1420 L=PTCPYES
N1430 G01 G300 X=2.00000 Y=-75.75000
N1440 P014=P069
N1450 L=PONINT2
N1460 G01 G300 Z=P014
N1470 G68
N1480 L=PBLOCCAC
N1490 L=PRPMOK01
N1500 M33200
N1510 G01 G42 X=-73.75000 Y=-75.75000  F=350 
N1520 G02 X=2.00000 Y=0.00000  I=2.00000 J=-75.75000 
N1530 M136
N1540 G01 X=880.00000 Y=0.00000  F=2200
N1550 G01 X=900.00000 Y=0.00000  F=420 
N1560 G03 X=902.00000 Y=2.00000  I=900.00000 J=2.00000 F=1500
N1570 G01 X=902.00000 Y=22.00000  F=1500
N1580 G01 X=902.00000 Y=343.00000  F=2200 
N1590 G01 X=902.00000 Y=363.00000  F=420 
N1600 G03 X=900.00000 Y=365.00000  I=900.00000 J=363.00000 F=1500
N1610 G01 X=880.00000 Y=365.00000  F=1500
N1620 G01 X=22.00000 Y=365.00000  F=2200 
N1630 G01 X=2.00000 Y=365.00000  F=420 
N1640 G03 X=0.00000 Y=363.00000  I=2.00000 J=363.00000 F=1500
N1650 G01 X=0.00000 Y=343.00000  F=1500
N1660 G01 X=0.00000 Y=22.00000  F=2200 
N1670 G01 X=0.00000 Y=2.00000  F=420 
N1680 G03 X=2.00000 Y=0.00000  I=2.00000 J=2.00000 F=1500
N1690 G01 X=22.00000 Y=0.00000  F=1500
N1700 G01 X=32.00000 Y=0.00000  F=2200 
N1710 M137
N1720 G02 X=107.75000 Y=-75.75000  I=32.00000 J=-75.75000 
N1730 M021
N1740 G01 G40 X=32.00000 Y=-75.75000  
N1750 G01 G300 X=32.00000 Y=-75.75000 Z=80.00000+P102 
N1760 L=PTCPNO
N1770 L=PSBLOCCAC
N1780 L=POFFINT2

:ENDFOR
N1790 JM(P010=2):99999

N1800 JM:99999
:1000
N1810 L=PINITBATVENT
:FOR P500=P008 TO (P001-1)
N1820 L=PLETORIG
N1830 P502=0
N1840 P466=-15.00000
N1850 P467=203.70029
N1860 P460=26.00000
N1870 L=POSBV
N1880 P502=0
N1890 P466=225.90810
N1900 P467=-15.00000
N1910 P460=26.00000
N1920 L=POSBV
N1930 P502=0
N1940 P466=665.50118
N1950 P467=-15.00000
N1960 P460=26.00000
N1970 L=POSBV
N1980 P502=1
N1990 P466=806.67132
N2000 P467=89.33461
N2010 P460=120.00000
N2020 P461=0.00000
N2030 P462=0.00000
N2040 L=POSBV
N2050 P502=1
N2060 P466=806.67132
N2070 P467=276.96581
N2080 P460=120.00000
N2090 P461=0.00000
N2100 P462=0.00000
N2110 L=POSBV
N2120 P502=1
N2130 P466=449.27857
N2140 P467=171.53494
N2150 P460=120.00000
N2160 P461=0.00000
N2170 P462=0.00000
N2180 L=POSBV
N2190 P502=1
N2200 P466=111.54242
N2210 P467=264.45706
N2220 P460=120.00000
N2230 P461=0.00000
N2240 P462=0.00000
N2250 L=POSBV
N2260 P502=1
N2270 P466=99.03368
N2280 P467=91.12157
N2290 P460=120.00000
N2300 P461=0.00000
N2310 P462=0.00000
N2320 L=POSBV
:ENDFOR

:99999
N2330 L=PFINE
%
```

Comment: You have to pass the `re.MULTILINE` flag if you want a regex to cross line boundaries.  However, wouldn't this job be better in a text editor?  Why script it?

Comment: If you're on linux or macOS [sed](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/) may be an easier option than firing up python.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Sorry, I'm using Windows

Comment: @TimRoberts I'll take a look at ```re.MULTILINE```. And Notepad++ is good idea, and I tried it now. But the grease part is that the CNC Machine name changes throughout the files. And there are plenty of files generated during the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with `replace`:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r+') as f:
    text = f.read() # read everything in the file
    blocks = text.split('ENDFOR') #split text in blocks
    blocks = [i + 'ENDFOR' for i in blocks[:-1] if i] + [blocks[-1]] #add endfors 
    new_blocks = [block.replace("N1530 M136","N1530 M128").replace("N1710 M137","N1710 M129") if 'ST1="803"' in block else block for block in blocks]
    new_text = ''.join(new_blocks)
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as fn: #write to file
        fn.write(new_text)
```

Comment: ```replace``` function is really good, but first I need to find the place where to replace. Because it's not always the same lines and code. The ```ST1="803"``` is the only thing that doesn't change in the block of code, which can be used as an anchor to find the ```M136``` and replace it.

Comment: `replace` replaces the string everywhere in the text file so why would you need to find the location where to replace? Are there other blocks of text where this string shouldn't be replaced?

Comment: Yes, there are other blocks where it shouldn't be changed. Basically I need to find the ```M136``` between ```ST="803"``` and ```: ENDFOR```

Comment: I see, I have updated the code to split by blocks and only replace in the relevant block.

Comment: This helps a lot. Now it can find the Block with `ST1="803"` and change the parameter. But somehow after joining the Blocks together, it doesn't rewrite the whole text, only the last bit of the text file.

After those two blocks there is 
```:99999
N2330 L=PFINE
%
ENDFOR```

and the script just adds these in the bottom (because I deleted the `f.seek(0)`). If I leave it there then the script adds the last lines in the beginning of the text file.

Comment: Just write it to a new file (you could use the same filename to overwrite), I updated the answer. Depending the output you might need to use `text = ''.join(blocks[:-1])` if there is an extra trailing `ENDFOR`. If this doesn't work please update your question with the full text file so I can debug.

Comment: I've updated the FULL text file.
It's good now that it can output in another file.
But it doesn't replace the needed text in the output.
If I put `print(block)` after `block = block.replace("N1530 M136","N1530 M128").replace("N1710 M137","N1710 M129")` then it shows the replacement. But in the output file it's not changed.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code, it works now on the full file.

Comment: Amazing, that is what I was looking for.